# Can I Convert The Page into Post?

Tags: wordpress

I want to convert my website with the dynamic homepage. All my latest post will display on the homepage. I created a homepage when I started the website. I now want to convert that page as a post. So, It displays on blog section.

Comment: Did you try to search for this online? https://www.converticacommerce.com/support-maintenance/how-to-change-wordpress-page-to-post/

Comment: I find the solution from a blog yesterday. However, thanks for your recommendation. This one is more helpful.